# pygame.mouse.get_visible() Fails

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote a handy on-screen keyboard module that I can import and use when writing programs intended to run in tablet mode on my PC. Because I want to import and use this utility in many future programs, I want to store the current mouse position and the mouse visibility state at the start of the module, and then restore those conditions when the module exits. The .mouse.get_pos() command works just fine, but the .mouse.get_visible() command is failing, returning the error message: AttributeError: module 'pygame.mouse' has no attribute 'get_visible' The pygame mouse documentation lists this as a valid method (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html), and I see no indication that it has been depreciated or removed.

Here is a sample program that demonstrates the problem:

```
import pygame
from time import sleep
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((3000,2000),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
screen.fill(pygame.Color("lightblue"))
pygame.display.flip()

pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

print("\n pygame.mouse.get_pos() returned >>",pygame.mouse.get_pos())

try:
    print(" pygame.mouse.get_visible() returned >>",pygame.mouse.get_visible())
except:
    print(" pygame.mouse.get_visible() failed!")

print()    
sleep(0.5)
pygame.quit()
```

The accepted response will answer one or both of the following questions:

1.) Is this method broken/missing, or am I missing something obvious here?

2.) Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can obtain the visibility state without the get_visible() method, so that I can restore the state before leaving my keyboard module?

Comment: What version of pygame are you using? Did you try to update pygame?

Comment: I am using python 3.6.5 and pygame 1.9.4   Does my sample program work for you?

Comment: The current pygame version is 2.1.0. `pygame.mouse.get_visible()` works fine for me, and probably most other people.

Comment: Fair enough. I will update my pygame version when I get home this evening, and if this is at the root of my trouble, I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Rabbid76, I updated pygame on my system to 2.1.0 this evening, as you suggested, and it fixed the issue. pygame.mouse.get_visible() is now returning True or False, depending on mouse visibility. I would accept your answer if it were still available. Would you like to submit the answer again so I can give credit where due? I will allow 24 hours for your answer before writing the answer myself and closing the topic out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pygame.mouse.set_visible` is broken in older PyGame version. Update Pygame to the latest version.

On some systems it is necessary to handle the events before the changes to the mouse pointer take effect:

```py
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
print(" pygame.mouse.get_pos() returned >>",pygame.mouse.get_pos())

pygame.event.pump()

try:
    print(pygame.mouse.get_visible())
except:
    print(" pygame.mouse.get_visible() failed!")
```

See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Rabbid76. Unfortunately, adding 'pygame.event.pump()' did nothing. 'pygame.mouse.get_visible()' still fails. The method appears to be non-existent even though it is shown as valid in the documentation.

Comment: Rabbid in an earlier comment noted that pygame.mouse.get_visible() worked for him and suggested that I may need to update my version of pygame. This solved the problem. The get_visible() method is now working correctly. For this reason, I have accepted Rabbid76's answer even though the solution was given in a comment rather than in the answer itself. If you have run into the same issue with pygame.mouse.get_visible() as I had, try reinstalling pygame to the latest version. It worked for me.